# how can we use the viewmap of HERE in server-side (PHP)

Tags: here-api

how can I grap the data (map) from this api in PHP. I try it with Curl on PHP but that not work (null value on the variable).

Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTTPRest interface of the MapTile API.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/topics/quick-start-map-tile.html
see also https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/topics/key-concepts.html